# What is the meaning of posts.communityowned date?

Tags: support, data-explorer

There is a field in the `posts` table named communityowneddate. What is the meaning of that field? And in what case is the post owned by community?

Comment: Related: [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677/168244)

Answer (score 6):

It is the date and time when the post was converted to [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).